# await is not storing data in variable when promise is rejected

Tags: async-await, promise

I have used a async function to wait for the settlement of promise and store the result in a variable. But it is not storing incase the promise is rejected. It is stroing result when promise is resolve but not when promise is rejecte. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```js
async function umar() {
  let somevar = false;
  let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (somevar === true) {
      console.log('I am resolved');   
         resolve('resolved')
    }
    else {
      console.log('I am rejected.')
      reject('rejected')
    }
  })
  let myprom = await myPromise
  console.log(myprom)
  return myprom
}
let a = umar()
a.then((value)=>{
  console.log(value)
},()=>{console.log('I got an error.')})
```

I was expecting the await to store the value in variable in both cases(when promise is rejected and resolve) but it is not doing so incase promise is rejected.

Answer (score 1):

This is how `await` works.  When the promise is rejected, it `throws` and you have to catch the error locally with a `try/catch` if you want to see the error locally.  Your assignment statement `let myprom = await myPromise` will not be executed when `myPromise` rejects.

Promise rejections have to be caught in a `.catch()`, with the second callback to `.then(fn1, fn2)` or, if using `await` with a `try/catch` around the `await` (or sometimes you let the rejection propagate out of the `async` function and the caller can then catch the rejection.

In your `umar()` function, when `myPromise` rejects, the function will throw at the point of `await myPromise` and the promise that the async parent function returned will then reject with the same error that myPromise rejected with (as the `async` function automatically catches the `throw` and turns it into a rejection or its promise).  You can either wrap a `try/catch` around that `await` to catch the error or in your code example, you can catch the error where you call `umar()` which you are already doing.  If you log the actual error there, you would see the error you expect:

```
let a = umar();
a.then((value) => {
  console.log(value)
}, (err) => {
  // log the error 
  console.log('I got an error.', err);
});
```